# Sitecore 8: Sharing Layout among different languages

Tags: layout, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a slight problem here and a doubt. I have created a page which has three components added in three different placeholders. This page was created for English version. I need this page and the components to get added in German version of the page as well.

I read a few articles that illustrate the use of layout deltas and "Final layout" feature of Sitecore 8 but got a little confused over this matter.

[Article1](http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-8-versioned-layouts-mixed-feelings/)

Also, I have checked the **__Renderings** setting in /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections/Layout and the **Shared** field is checked. Still the layout is not shared.

Am i missing any settings ? Do I need to every time create both versions i.e. repeat the layout steps for German versions as well ?

All suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Sitecore 8.0 and adding the component via the Experience Editor then you will need to add the components to each language variation of the Item, i.e. once for English and once for German. This is because the components are stored against the `Final Layout` field when added through the Experience Editor and the field is language specific.

The only option you have is to add the components to the `Shared Layout` manually by selecting the Presentation > Details from the tabs.

If you need to add the same components to all language variations at the same time then I suggest you upgrade to Sitecore 8.1 which will enable you to do that via `Edit all versions` option in the ribbon:

[image: Edit All Versions]

---

**Edit:** As of Sitecore 8.1 update-1, the Shared Layout can be edited using the "Layout Switcher" under the Presentation tab:

[image: Sitecore 8.1]

Comment: However, I will have to create the German version through content editor. right ? And only then if i add any components they will get stored in Final Layout field (as versioned layout). Correct?

Comment: In Sitecore 7, however, by checking __Renderings--> Shared field, the layouts are shared among language versions. But it seems that this is not working with Sitecore 8. !?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. This changed between Sitecore 7 and 8, in which a language specific layout was introduced.

Comment: Ok. I went through this one article that too says in sitecore 8, we need to repeat steps for different languages...

Comment: FYI: As of 8.1 (rev. 151207), "Edit all versions" button got removed. You can modify shared layouts clicking "Final Layout" under  "Presentation" instead. But if you are running multisite (or have more than one <site> in your config), then you need to set Preview.ResolveSite to true. See: http://ggullentops.blogspot.co.uk/2015/11/previewresolvesite-and-disabled-shared.html